# android accelerometer maximum value

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am trying to get the maximum value from the accelerometer in android in a given time period and don't want continuous streaming value. just a constant maximum value say in the last 1 second.

```
private SensorEventListener sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
        float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
        float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

        accelerationCurrentValue = Math.sqrt((x*x + y*y + z*z));

       double changeInAcceleration = Math.abs( accelerationCurrentValue - accelerationPreviousValue);
       accelerationPreviousValue = accelerationCurrentValue;
      
        //update text views
        txt_currentAccel.setText("Current = "  + accelerationCurrentValue);
        txt_prevAccel.setText("Previous = "  + accelerationPreviousValue);
        txt_acceleration.setText("Acceleration change = " + changeInAcceleration);
        txt_maximum.setText("Max value " + accelerationMax);
        prog_shakeMeter.setProgress((int)changeInAcceleration);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't too hard.  You just need to keep all the events that happened in the last second in a queue.  Then you can iterate over it and find the max.

```
class AccelerationData {
  public float accel;
  public long timestamp;
}

Queue<AccelerationData> queue = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
        float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
        float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

        accelerationCurrentValue = Math.sqrt((x*x + y*y + z*z));
        queue.add(new AccelerationData(accelerationCurrentValue, sensorEvent.timestamp));
        while(queue.peek().time < sensorEvent.timestamp- 1000000000) {
            queue.remove();
        }
        float accelMax = 0;
        for(AccelerationData data : queue) {
            accelMax = Math.max(accelMax, data.accel);
        }
        //continue with your code
```

Edit from original code:  change if to while to handle multiple expired entries

Comment: how to specify my duration. In queue.peek().time where the 'time' variable has to be defined somewhere. The problem arises as to how to give a value of 1 second to 'time'

Comment: Sensor time is in nanoseconds.  So 1 second would be 1000000000 nanoseconds.  You just subtract it, like I did in the while statement.  Then you remove it if its too old.